# PHP IF to display HTML based on session isset

Tags: php, html, session, if-statement

I have the below code, which gives no errors, but it only ever displays the Logout button, I don't really have much else to say.

```
<?php
    if(isset($_SESSION)):?>
            <a href="endsession.php"><div class= "buttons feature">Logout</div></a>
    <?php    
    else:?>
        <a href = "javascript:void(0)" onclick = "document.getElementById('light').style.display='block';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block'"><div class= "buttons feature">LOGIN</div></a>

    <?php endif; 
?>
```

The Logout button runs:

```
<?php
session_start();
session_destroy();
?>
```

And have I have code in my main page which displays values stored in the session based on if the session isset, so I know it is destroying the session, and when I'm logged in it is set.

I just don't understand why it always only displays the html from the if where the session doesn't exist.

I've probably made a silly mistake, so sorry if I have.

All help appreciated -Tom

Comment: Sessions also include a name, like `$_SESSION['name']`, so you probably didn't set that one. For example `$_SESSION['name'] = 'Something';` and then use it later with `echo $_SESSION['name']`.

Comment: This is checking for a session in general, I'm not checking for a specific session variable I've set. 
Also I don't quite follow what you mean, you say sessions have a name, then just says "like $_SESSION" instead of "like $_SESSION['Name']"

Comment: The `$_SESSION` variable is always set, but you actually have to use it like an array and pass keys with values into it for your logic to make sense.\

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The `$_SESSION` variable is always set - regardless if you have initialized the session or not. You must actually assing something in `$_SESSION` array to get results. For example after succesful login do this:

```
$_SESSION['is_logged_in'] = true;
```

And then you can check

```
if(isset($_SESSION['is_logged_in']))
```

anywhere you want (instead of your `if(isset($_SESSION))`).

Comment: This doesn't cover how to actually display the HTML in the event of a `true` case.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
if(isset($_SESSION) AND $_SESSION):?>

                <a href="endsession.php"><div class= "buttons feature">Logout</div></a>
        <?php    
        else:?>

        <a href = "javascript:void(0)" onclick = "document.getElementById('light').style.display='block';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block'"><div class= "buttons feature">LOGIN</div></a>

        <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting `$_SESSION`

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;
```

checking `$_SESSION`:

```
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])){
  echo "logged in";
}
```